# Confused about partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am having some issues understanding what should I keep constant and what not in certain cases when I take partial derivatives. Specifically in this kind of situation: say we have a function

$$f(x,y) = x^3+7y^2$$

and we also know that $y=2x+1$ and we need to find the partial derivative with respect to $x$ at a given point, say $\frac{\partial f(2,3)}{\partial x}$. From what I understood, when taking partial derivatives with respect to a variable, you need to keep the other constant, in which case, if I do that above (keeping $y$ constant) I would get, $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=3x^2$, so I get $12$. However, if I plug $x$ in $y$ explicitly I would get $$f(x,y) = x^3+7(2x+1)^2$$ so,

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=3x^2+28(2x+1)$$

So, I get $152$. What should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We split the task into two parts. At first we look at obtaining a partial derivative with respect to $x$. Then we consider the evaluation at the specific point $(2,3)$.

**Chain rule revisited:** In order to better see what's going on, we consider a somewhat more general situation and then we will see how OPs special case fits into this setting.

We start with OPs real-valued function $f$, namely
\begin{align*}
&f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}\\
&f(x,y)=x^3+7y^2\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We put the relation $y=2x+1$ in a slighty more general context, which might help to make the application of the chain-rule more plausible. We consider $x$ and $y$ as functions of a variable $t$:
> \begin{align*}
> x&=x(t)=t\\
> y&=y(t)=2t+1\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> and define a new real-valued function $\varphi$ as
> \begin{align*}
> &\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\\
> &\varphi(t)=f(x(t),y(t))\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

We can now write
\begin{align*}
\varphi(t)=f(x(t),y(t))=f(t,2t+1)\tag{4}
\end{align*} and have the same situation as OP when he is using the relation $y=2x+1$ and taking $f(x,y(x))=f(x,2x+1)$. The benefit is that we can now apply the chain rule using a familiar derivation:

> On the one hand we obtain from (1) - (3):
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{d\varphi}{dt}}
> &=\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}\,\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}\,\frac{dy}{dt}\\
> &=3\left(x(t)\right)^2\cdot 1+14y(t)\cdot 2\\
> &=3t^2+14(2t+1)\cdot 2\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=3t^2+56t+28}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> on the other hand we obtain from (4):
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{d\varphi}{dt}}
> &=\frac{d}{dt}f(t,2t+1)\\
> &=\frac{d}{dt}\left(t^3+7(2t+1)^2\right)\\
> &=3t^2+28(2t+1)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=3t^2+56t+28}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with (5).

**Conclusion:** We conclude from (5) and (6) the following derivation of OP is valid:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{d}{d x}f(x,y(x))=3x^2+28(2x+1)}
\end{align*}

**Evaluation at $(2,3)$:**

We consider $f(x,y)=x^3+7y^2$ as above and evaluate the partial derivative wrt $x$ at $(x,y)=(2,3)$. We obtain this way
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)\Bigg|_{(x,y)=(2,3)}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^3+7y^2\right)\Bigg|_{(x,y)=(2,3)}\\
&=\left(3x^2\right)\Bigg|_{(x,y)=(2,3)}\\
&=12
\end{align*}
but this is completely independent from the rule $y=2x+1$. In fact it cannot be conveniently connected with evaluation at a point $(x,y)=(2,3)$, since this point is not an element of the line $y=2x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it depends (slightly) on the intent of the problem.  When I read the problem as you've written it, I see this:

> Given that $y = 2x+1$ and  $f(x,y) = x^{3} + 7y^{2},$ calculate $\frac{\partial f(2,3)}{\partial x}$.

In that statement, I interpret this as $f$ is a function of two variables, $x$ and $y$, and we are asked to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ and evaluate the result at $(x,y) = (2,3)$.  In this case, the fact that $y$ depends on $x$ isn't relevant, because since $f$ depends explicitly on $x$ and $y$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ mean *hold $y$ constant and differentiate with respect to $x$*.  That gives us $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = 3x^{2}\implies \frac{\partial f(2,3)}{\partial x} = 12.$$

Now, if instead the problem was phrased as

> Given that $y = 2x+1$ and  $f(x,y) = x^{3} + 7y^{2},$ calculate the total rate of change of $f$ with respect to $x$ at $(2,3)$.

In this case, I would interpret the problem as asking for the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), which accounts for dependencies among the variables.  In this case, your answer would be $$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2+28(2x+1) \implies \frac{df}{dx}(2,3) = 152.$$

If the original problem does indeed ask for $\frac{\partial f(2,3)}{\partial x}$ then I would say the first interpretation is correct.  If you are adding that notation yourself, it may be the case that the second interpretation is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess what confuses me is the assumption that y is kept constant. If I vary x and y depends on x, how can I assume that y is constant, too? I also found, for example, this https://archive.uea.ac.uk/jtm/slides/14/sld14p5.pdf. In the first example (pg. 5) z is a function of x and y and they take the partial derivative with respect to r. If I would do as in my first approach, I would get zero. What is the difference between what they do and my example?

Comment: The difference there is that $x$ and $y$ were functions of $r$, and $z$ was not explicitly a function of $r$, so in some sense they are abusing notation in writing $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$ to mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} z(x(r),y(r))$, which is different from  $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} z(x,y)$.

Comment: If $y = 2x + 1$, then you can't keep $y$ constant.  Any change in $x$ will always lead to a change in $y$.  Note that this isn't always the case.  If $y = x^2$, then there is one point where $y$ is constant (though it might not be where you are looking).  Just because a question can be asked doesn't mean it actually makes sense under the hood.

Comment: @DMcMor sorry I am still confused. Can't I just also write my function as f(x(x),y(x)), with x(x) = x and y(x) = 2x+1 and I would get the same thing as they got? And if that is the case, shouldn't I take the derivative of y with respect to x too? I am still not clear when can I keep a variable constant and when not, given that that variable depends on the one we take the derivative with respect to.

Comment: @johnnyb so you are saying that y shouldn't be kept constant? So is the second approach (giving 152) correct?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. If you are trying to do a partial derivative, it just doesn't work.

Comment: @johnnyb you mean that the partial derivative of f with respect to x is not defined in this case?

Comment: The short answer is that your question is ambiguous.  All three answers - 12, 152, and undefined, are all correct depending on the actual question that you are asking.

Comment: If the question is: (a) what is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its first parameter at (2, 3), then the answer is 12. If the question is, (b) what is the derivative of the composite function with respect to its only parameter, then the answer is 152. If the question is, given the dual constraints, how much if $f$ moving with respect to its first parameter if the second one isn't moving, then answer is undefined because the first parameter can't move without the second.

Comment: I didn't realize this would cause so much discussion on a Sunday night - I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely important to make some distinctions with notation. Given a function ${f(x,y)}$, then ${\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}$ means "treating $y$ as a constant, what is the derivative of $f$ with respect to ${x}$?" <- this does not, on it's own, necessary tell you about how $f$ changes overall with respect to $x$. In order to know this, we must use the multi-variable chain rule, which is:
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}
$$
notice if ${\frac{dy}{dx}=0}$, i.e. ${x}$ and ${y}$ are independent, then ${\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}$ (i.e. the partial derivative tells us all we need to know about how $f$ changes with respect to $x$).

Comment: Thanks for this. What I don't get it is, how can you ask in the first place the question of how f changes with x when y is constant. Given that y depends on x explicitly, how can you assume that dy/dx=0? Thinking in terms of a physical system, if I move x a bit and I measure f (without touching y at all) I will have the variation of y automatically included in my measurement of f, simply because y depends on x. What am I missing?